# Determinant of a block-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices

> [image]

---

I can do the first part, where $A$ is a $1\times1$ matrix.

$$\det(C) = \Sigma_i (-1)^{i+j} C_{ij} \det(F_{ij})$$

$F_{ij}$ is the co-factor matrix (a matrix that includes all the elements of $C$ except for the ith row and jth column)

If we set $j=1$ then the only value for $i$ for which $C_{ij}\neq0$ is 1.  we also know that $C_{11}=Det(A)$ and therfoer the co-factor matrix is $F_{11}B$.

Our expression above becomes $Det(C)=Det(A)det(B)$ as required.

The second bit, however, I couldn't do via induction.  I did find one method however:

$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}
    A & O \\
    O & I_m 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    I_n & O \\
    O & B
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

$$\det(C) = \det\begin{bmatrix} A   & O   \\
                                O   & I_m \end{bmatrix}
            \det\begin{bmatrix} I_n & O   \\
                                O   & B.  \end{bmatrix}$$

Which is clearly (using similar logic to above) $\det(C) = \det(A) \det(B)$

Can anyone please

1. tell me if my proof is valid and
2. show me how to solve this via induction?

Comment: I am too lazy to write an answer, but if you apply Laplace formula to the first row of a matrix with $A$ of dimension $n+1$, you get the sum of $n+1$ element containing the determinants of block matrices with block of dimensions $n$ and $m$, where by hypotesis the product rule applies.

Comment: We haven't covered the Laplace formula and so, although I can look it up, I don't think that its what the question wants

Edit: Laplace is just the the co-factor expansion I did, i didn't know what it was called.  Although I thought of that and can't see how.